plumbing issues moving laundry room
I am considering remodeling my house.
Currently the water using spaces Bath/Kitchen/Laundry are all clustered  together.
Drainage goes to the basement and then exits the house.
Obviously keeping them all in a group makes the plumbing simpler, but is this required?
Could I move the laundry to some other part of the house (not in the same cluster) to have room to expand the kitchen?

That depends how far away you want to move it, and how much work you want to do.  You need to maintain a minimum slope for the pipes, and the farther away you go, the more vertical drop you need.  Depending whether your pipes are between floors or in a slab, that may drive how much work (i.e. expense) it is.

Yes.  The horizontal drain pipes need to have 1/8 to 1/4 inch slope per foot, so that will need to be worked out for the distance the laundry is moved to, from the main drain.

If possible, it will be much easier if the drain pipe can go in the same direction as the joists/in between two joists.

@Hueamann, make that an answer. It makes the most sense with the info provided.

@RMDman yeah, but the limited info is why I didn't want to make it an answer—"it depends" is hardly definitive.
